# Hive index error

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm facing issues while building an index on multiple columns in a Hive(0.9.0) table.

```
describe nas_comps;
OK
leg_id  int
ds_name string
dep_date        string
crr_code        string
flight_no       string
orgn    string
dstn    string
physical_cap    int
adjusted_cap    int
closed_cap      int
comp_code       string
```

This works :

```
CREATE INDEX nas_comps_legid ON TABLE nas_comps (leg_id) AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
```

But this doesn't :

```
    CREATE INDEX nas_comps_legid_compcode ON TABLE nas_comps (leg_id,comp_code) AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Check the index columns, they should appear in the table being indexed.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I guess the index is somehow able to recognize only the first column because even this failed :

```
CREATE INDEX nas_comps_compcode ON TABLE nas_comps (comp_code) AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Check the index columns, they should appear in the table being indexed.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I checked [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4251) issue but I don't think this is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Think Hive does not support indexing on partitioned columns.. please check if comp code is a partitioned column..

As far as indexing on multiple columns, it should work..

Comment: Are u sure that 'Hive does not support indexing on partitioned columns'. Yes, comp_code is the partitioned column and I had the similar suspicion earlier but no where in documentation, this notification exists.

Comment: From the book _Programming Hive, O'Reilly_ on the page 118, it seems that you can indexing on partitioned columns. The version of Hive used in this book is v0.9.0

Comment: I believe this issue was present in 0.10 version also. That you cannot index on the partitioned columns of managed tables!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE INDEX nas_comps_legid ON TABLE nas_comps (leg_id) AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

or

CREATE INDEX nas_comps_legid ON TABLE nas_comps (leg_id) AS 'compact' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

**Yes, this is working**

Comment: It looks like you may have missed the issue the user described.